# How to count the shared files with command and return the variable?

Tags: batch-file, command, shared-directory

Here is the code that I used.

```
for /f %%a in ('"dir /a:-d /s /b %Path%|find /c ":\""') do set check=%%a
```

This command can run correctly under the local environment, and return the variable "check".
(That means how many files in the %Path%)

However, when setting up the %Path% to shared path, the variable "check" always return 0.

Even I can use `dir %Path%` successfully.

How to fix the code to return variable from shared folder?

Comment: Don't mess with the system variable `%PATH%`. Use another name (maybe `%MyPath%` or `%folder%`). `%PATH%` tells Windows where to find its executables.

Comment: Show the exact name of the shared folder.

Comment: @Stephan Thanks for the suggestion. I used `%CountFloderPath%` actually. And the full path is `\\192.168.168.128\sharefolder_test\count`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to perform that search is to count the number of items which are not blank. So, you could perform the search like this:

```
for /f %%a in ('dir /a:-d /s /b %_myPath% ^|find /c /v ""') do set "check=%%a"
```

I agree with Stephan that you should not use %PATH% as your variable. Also, you should use quotes around the set command. If this doesn't work, we'd need to know the exact name and location of your path variable.

Comment: Thanks!! I use that solution and then it works!